# Parse a string to get the array details

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting the below response from the server as shown below

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"Errors\":\"\",\"Message\":\"\",\"Output\":\"\",\"TokenID\":\"F106457749C\",\"OrgID\":0,\"OutputObject\":{\"Details\":{\"CatalogDetail\":[{\"CatalogID\":74,\"CategoryID\":22,\"ShortCatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"CatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"Description\":\"Use this catalog for email forwarding \",\"IsVendor\":false,\"IsPackage\":false,\"AncestorParent_CategoryID\":58,\"IsEntitled\":0,\"CategoryName\":\"Email\",\"ServiceCatalogBGColor\":\"\"}],\"BaseUrl\":\"https://serviceimg-attachments\"}}}",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
    "set-cookie": [
      "ASP.NET_SessionId=m0jbtyi12mzefkkyh3xd4i0m; path=/; HttpOnly",
      ".ASPXAUTH=41C6BC3E87DBF106457749C; path=/"
    ],
    "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "date": "Mon, 15 Oct 2018 17:51:09 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "779"
  }
}
```

I want to parse the body reponse.body which is a string. The reason for the parsing is to get the array  `response.body.OutputObject.Details.CatalogDetail`. But when i do it i get `Details as undefined`. Can anyone help me to get the CatalogDetail Array.

Thanks
Arul

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse() function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing it in following way and it's working. I am not able to parse complete object. Get body object separately like.

```
var body = JSON.parse(res["body"])
```

And then use it in following way.

```
JSON.parse(res["body"]).OutputObject.Details.CatalogDetail
```

Comment: @Arulvelu You can accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
var myObject = JSON.parse("my json string");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse json before access the obj, [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will parse the json string.

```
var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because body's value is in string format and if you want to access it as a json format you need to parse it first, check below code snipet for more information.

```js
var response = {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"Errors\":\"\",\"Message\":\"\",\"Output\":\"\",\"TokenID\":\"F106457749C\",\"OrgID\":0,\"OutputObject\":{\"Details\":{\"CatalogDetail\":[{\"CatalogID\":74,\"CategoryID\":22,\"ShortCatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"CatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"Description\":\"Use this catalog for email forwarding \",\"IsVendor\":false,\"IsPackage\":false,\"AncestorParent_CategoryID\":58,\"IsEntitled\":0,\"CategoryName\":\"Email\",\"ServiceCatalogBGColor\":\"\"},{\"CatalogID\":75,\"CategoryID\":22,\"ShortCatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding2\",\"CatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding2\",\"Description\":\"Use this catalog for email forwarding \",\"IsVendor\":false,\"IsPackage\":false,\"AncestorParent_CategoryID\":58,\"IsEntitled\":0,\"CategoryName\":\"Email\",\"ServiceCatalogBGColor\":\"\"}],\"BaseUrl\":\"https://serviceimg-attachments\"}}}",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
    "set-cookie": [
      "ASP.NET_SessionId=m0jbtyi12mzefkkyh3xd4i0m; path=/; HttpOnly",
      ".ASPXAUTH=41C6BC3E87DBF106457749C; path=/"
    ],
    "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "date": "Mon, 15 Oct 2018 17:51:09 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "779"
  }
}
var body = JSON.parse(response.body)
var Catelogs = body.OutputObject.Details.CatalogDetail;
for(var i=0;i<Catelogs.length;i++){
    console.log("CatalogID : " + Catelogs[i].CatalogID)
    console.log("ShortCatalogName : " + Catelogs[i].ShortCatalogName);
}
$.each(Catelogs, function( index, value ) {
  console.log(  "CatalogID : " + value.CatalogID );  
  console.log(  "ShortCatalogName : " + value.ShortCatalogName );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can use simple for loop or $.each loop to iterate through the array

Comment: I know by parsing the string you will convert that to object and get the value . But my question is to get the catalogDetails:[ ] values. I need the complete array

Comment: @Arulvelu check now and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the body as json. Probably whatever framework you are using has a `response.json()`-like method but you can just use `JSON.parse`.

```
response = {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"Errors\":\"\",\"Message\":\"\",\"Output\":\"\",\"TokenID\":\"F106457749C\",\"OrgID\":0,\"OutputObject\":{\"Details\":{\"CatalogDetail\":[{\"CatalogID\":74,\"CategoryID\":22,\"ShortCatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"CatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"Description\":\"Use this catalog for email forwarding \",\"IsVendor\":false,\"IsPackage\":false,\"AncestorParent_CategoryID\":58,\"IsEntitled\":0,\"CategoryName\":\"Email\",\"ServiceCatalogBGColor\":\"\"}],\"BaseUrl\":\"https://serviceimg-attachments\"}}}",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
    "set-cookie": [
      "ASP.NET_SessionId=m0jbtyi12mzefkkyh3xd4i0m; path=/; HttpOnly",
      ".ASPXAUTH=41C6BC3E87DBF106457749C; path=/"
    ],
    "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "date": "Mon, 15 Oct 2018 17:51:09 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "779"
  }
}
body = JSON.parse(response.body)
body.OutputObject.Details.CatalogDetail
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(data.body)` to parse the string to JSON and you can do any operations,

Read More [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Below is the snippet

```js
var data = {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"Errors\":\"\",\"Message\":\"\",\"Output\":\"\",\"TokenID\":\"F106457749C\",\"OrgID\":0,\"OutputObject\":{\"Details\":{\"CatalogDetail\":[{\"CatalogID\":74,\"CategoryID\":22,\"ShortCatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"CatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"Description\":\"Use this catalog for email forwarding \",\"IsVendor\":false,\"IsPackage\":false,\"AncestorParent_CategoryID\":58,\"IsEntitled\":0,\"CategoryName\":\"Email\",\"ServiceCatalogBGColor\":\"\"}],\"BaseUrl\":\"https://serviceimg-attachments\"}}}",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
    "set-cookie": [
      "ASP.NET_SessionId=m0jbtyi12mzefkkyh3xd4i0m; path=/; HttpOnly",
      ".ASPXAUTH=41C6BC3E87DBF106457749C; path=/"
    ],
    "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "date": "Mon, 15 Oct 2018 17:51:09 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "779"
  }
};
var output = JSON.parse(data.body);
console.log(output.OutputObject.Details.CatalogDetail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse and then access property 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors for more ref.

```
  var obj = {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "body": "{\"Errors\":\"\",\"Message\":\"\",\"Output\":\"\",\"TokenID\":\"F106457749C\",\"OrgID\":0,\"OutputObject\":{\"Details\":{\"CatalogDetail\":[{\"CatalogID\":74,\"CategoryID\":22,\"ShortCatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"CatalogName\":\"Email Forwarding\",\"Description\":\"Use this catalog for email forwarding \",\"IsVendor\":false,\"IsPackage\":false,\"AncestorParent_CategoryID\":58,\"IsEntitled\":0,\"CategoryName\":\"Email\",\"ServiceCatalogBGColor\":\"\"}],\"BaseUrl\":\"https://serviceimg-attachments\"}}}",
      "headers": {
        "cache-control": "private",
        "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
        "set-cookie": [
          "ASP.NET_SessionId=m0jbtyi12mzefkkyh3xd4i0m; path=/; HttpOnly",
          ".ASPXAUTH=41C6BC3E87DBF106457749C; path=/"
        ],
        "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
        "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
        "date": "Mon, 15 Oct 2018 17:51:09 GMT",
        "connection": "close",
        "content-length": "779"
      }
    }

    var formated = JSON.parse(obj.body);

    var CatalogDetail = formated.OutputObject.Details.CatalogDetail[0];
    console.log(CatalogDetail);
```